# "Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package." while trying to install Firestorm

Tags: package-management, software-installation

I'm trying to install [Firestorm](https://wiki.firestormviewer.org/downloads) on my laptop, but I keep getting this error:

```
william@william-HP-Pavilion-dv6000-EY799AV-ABA:~$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
[sudo] password for william: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: 1st off: is your problem that you can not install ia32-libs OR that firestorm tells you that it needs ia32-libs and you then tried to install it yourself? If the latter the answer will not help you. You need to tell the maintainer/creator of this package to update it so it uses multi-arch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Package <package> has no installation candidate" mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14685/what-does-package-package-has-no-installation-candidate-mean)

Answer (score 0):

The package name is `ia32-libs-multiarch` and you should be able to install it with `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch`.

Comment: now when i try and open firestorm i get a window creation error and in running ubuntu 12.04 LTS i get the same error when i try and run secondlife viewer too