# Package 'openbsd-inetd' has no installation candidate

Tags: installation, apt, package-management

When I try to install `openbsd-inetd`, it shows

```
root@amsys-G41MT-S2PT:/home/amsys# sudo apt-get install openbsd-inetd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package openbsd-inetd is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'openbsd-inetd' has no installation candidate
```

What is meaning of `E: Package 'openbsd-inetd' has no installation candidate`?

Comment: Related (duplicate?) http://askubuntu.com/q/14685/176889

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the package *does* exist ([package search here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=openbsd-inetd&searchon=names)). My only suggestion is that you have somehow incomplete package listings.

Try this command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

The retry

```
sudo apt-get install openbsd-inetd
```

---

You can find further information about this error here:

- [What does Package <package> has no installation candidate mean?](https://askubuntu.com/a/14693/176889)