# Time and Date Not Available

Tags: time, date

My time and date not on the menu bar and the clock is not in the system settings.

I ran `sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime` and received this error:

```
Package indicator-datetime is not available, but is referred to by
another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'indicator-datetime' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: I did find killall unity-panel-service in another post, but not this possible duplicate you found. Thank you, but I am a novice user and need to understand what killall does. It says it will re-initialize the top panel, but I am afraid the command sounds like the whole panel will disappear.

Comment: `killall` kills all running instances of the program mentioned after it, in this case `unity-panel-service`. Once it is killed, it will restart by itself correctly. type `man killall` to see the manual for this command.

Comment: Nothing changed. Perhaps that is what "E: Package 'indicator-datetime' has no installation candidate" means?

Comment: the `apt get` command looks in various Ubuntu repositories in the Internet for the program you want to install, downloads, and installs it. The error means it couldn't find any program by the name `indicator-datetime` to download and install. This may be because this program is now built into `unity-panel-service`.

Comment: That makes sense. What should I type in the terminal now?

Comment: Try the killall command again. Just hit **Up Arrow** till you see the previous command and hit enter. For some reason the unity-panel-service is not initializing properly. It may work the next time.

Answer (score 1):

This is telling you that `indicator-datetime` isn't listed in the repositories in your sources. You may need to check that this package is available for your version of Ubuntu and/or add the required repository.

See [What does Package <package> has no installation candidate mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14685/what-does-package-package-has-no-installation-candidate-mean) for a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Dash and search for *Time & Date*;
2. go to the *Clock* tab;
3. make sure *Show a clock in the menu bar* is checked:

[image: Time & Date settings]