# How to install suggested package after installation main package?

Tags: apt, package-management

I just install chromium-browser and installation list some suggested packages to install and I continued installation and done it.

```
$ sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 The following extra packages will be installed:
   chromium-browser-l10n chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
 Suggested packages:
   webaccounts-chromium-extension unity-chromium-extension chromiumflashplugin
```

Then I decide to install a suggested packages that listed in above installation progress but I get error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install chromiumflashplugin
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 Package chromiumflashplugin is not available, but is referred to by another package.
 This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
 is only available from another source

 E: Package 'chromiumflashplugin' has no installation candidate
```

I tried also with following the command:

```
$ sudo apt-get -o APT::Install-Suggests="true" install chromium-browser

 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 chromium-browser is already the newest version.
 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 364 not upgraded.
```

How can I install this package? If it is only available from another source why(?) installation suggest that?

Comment: @Whaaaaaat Also visit [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/14685/256099).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why?

---

Developers are human and are lazy.  Instead of creating a separate package manifest for each version/distribution/package list of their DEB file, they just use one master one. The suggested packages are part of this developer-declared manifest. They are just too lazy and/or overworked to update this.

The package was removed from another repo, so it no longer exists in reality, but the manifest still calls to it. Install a similar/replacement package instead.

### How?

---

In your case, you are trying to install Flash. Run and restart browser:

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

Comment: In this case, you should have Flash... If not, it's a Chromium problem, not a Ubuntu one.

Comment: Ok it fixed after `dist-upgrade` and `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer` for firefox. but still in chromium not fixed. thank you I will install that with another way. bye ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may install `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` package. It is the Flash plugin from Chrome.

Actually it downloads Chrome Browser and extracts only `libpepflashplayer.so` from it.