# fresh install, python-software-properties unmet dependencies

Tags: 12.04, python, dependencies, curl

attention: This might be more a question for "gis.stackexchange" but it is Ubuntu-related
Geonode 2.0 is available for Ubuntu 12.04 but not for Ubuntu 14.04. According to the docs it should be sufficient to make an

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:geonode/release
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install geonode
```

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 12.04 with 64bit architecture, with a default LAMP configuration  made an apt-get update and it already fails on the first line:

```
Depends: python-pycurl but is not installable
```

The first line works on Ubuntu 14.04 but geonode will not be installable on 14.04. I am somewhere stucked. 
I have no idea to get this python-pycurl

Comment: I can't as I don't come so far. I already fail at sudo apt-get install python-software-properties as I have unmet dependencies to python-pycurl

Comment: Then first add output for `sudo apt-get install python-software-properties`

Comment: sorry for the image but I can't copy from my virtual server's (running on vmware) terminal: https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/656x231q90/674/ggdtqG.png

Comment: Also visit [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/14685/256099) & [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/140246/256099)

Comment: @Pandya thanks for the links, but I can't see how the proposed soultions there might help in my case.

Comment: @butcher You might want to add details to the question (by [edit]ing) t explain specifically why you believe the answers to those questions do *not* address this one. That might keep this from being closed as a duplicate of them, but more importantly, by directing people toward the aspects of your problem that are different, someone may be lead to figure out a solution. Thanks!