# Software center not found

Tags: software-center

whenever trying to install sofware center by the command

```
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

it is saying

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package software-center is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'software-center' has no installation candidate
```

plz help

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does Package <package> has no installation candidate mean?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14685/what-does-package-package-has-no-installation-candidate-mean)

Answer (score 1):

It obviously means that the packge "software-center" could not be found. This may have many reasons.

1. Check the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` to see whether it contains a line like this:

   `deb http://*.archive.ubuntu.com/` ....
   Where the * may have been replaced by a subdomain (like de., fr., etc.) or also can be omnitted.
   If the line begins with a hash sign (#), remove that hash sign. Do not remove hash sign before text comments.
2. Update your repository index by using `sudo apt-get update` first, then try again.
3. If it fails, please post your file  `/etc/apt/sources.list`.