# Can't seem to get Pipelight to install

Tags: apt, software-installation, pipelight

I've been able to complete all the steps from

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install pipelight-multi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package pipelight-multi is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'pipelight-multi' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: that's strange. What does the output of `apt-cache search pipelight` list?

Comment: also, the output of `dpkg -l | grep pipelight` will show what is installed (if anything)

Comment: @mchid i tryed those 2 commands and nothin happend

Comment: That sounds like the ppa is not installed. What about `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ | grep pipelight` ?

Comment: @mchid http://paste.ubuntu.com/9628743/ is what i got

Comment: IDK, all I can recommend is trying `sudo apt-get update` again before trying again and if it still fails, you can always download the deb packages from here https://launchpad.net/~pipelight/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+sourcepub/4611331/+listing-archive-extra and install the deb file by right clicking and choosing to open it with software center, synaptic, or gdebi. i386.deb for 32bit and amd64.deb for 64 of course.

Comment: @ANewGuy4 what version of ubuntu are you using? I believe your problem is about [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists) not about installation of pipelight.

Comment: @KasiyA i fixed the 404 errors but still cant install pipelight im using 
Precise Pangolin 12.04

Comment: Then I have no other idea. sorry ;(

Answer (score 1):

Try these commands from this [source](http://pipelight.net/cms/install/installation-ubuntu.html):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight-multi
sudo pipelight-plugin --update
```

Comment: ive already tryed that one its the install pipelight-multi that always cant complete

Comment: I just sudo apt-get install pipelight*

Comment: @ANewGuy4 kasiya is correct you prob. need pipelight-multi and it should be available to you if you have the ppa enabled.

Comment: Ill try again and show you the complete step by step

Comment: (precise)lelouch@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight-multi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package pipelight-multi is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'pipelight-multi' has no installation candidate

Comment: @ANewGuy4 Please run all commands one by one. [I don't have any problem in installation](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9628708/). If still not fixed see [What does Package <package> has no installation candidate mean?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14685/what-does-package-package-has-no-installation-candidate-mean) to fix that.

Comment: @KasiyA This is my steps 1st http://paste.ubuntu.com/9628721/. No problems. 2nd http://paste.ubuntu.com/9628726/. No problems other than those few files which were from when i did sudo apt-get install pipelight*. 3rd http://paste.ubuntu.com/9628728/. which wont work.

Comment: @ANewGuy4 You will need to fix your `W: Failed to fetch ... 404 not found` error first [2nd step](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9628726/). because your `sources.list` doesn't correctly update. follow [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists) to fix that one too.

Comment: @KasiyA i still cant get it to install keeps saying no installation candidate