# Can't install pipelight ubuntu 16.04

Tags: pipelight

```
sudo apt-get install pipelight
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package pipelight is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'pipelight' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't seem to get Pipelight to install](http://askubuntu.com/questions/565828/cant-seem-to-get-pipelight-to-install)

Comment: How do you add it as 15.10, Im not a full time linux user

Answer (score 2):

You have three options. Option one is wait for pipelight to be officially compiled and released then install as shown [here](http://pipelight.net/cms/install/installation-ubuntu.html). Option two is compile it yourself as is shown [here](http://pipelight.net/cms/install/compile-pipelight.html). Option three is to install from the .deb files for Ubuntu 15.10 which can be found [here](https://launchpad.net/~pipelight/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+packages). For option three you will need to install pipelight-multi - 0.2.8.2~ubuntu15.10.1 deb file and be sure you pick the 32bit or 64bit file depending on your computer hardware. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41332/how-do-i-check-if-i-have-a-32-bit-or-a-64-bit-os) is how you can check. As always, the safest and preferred option is option one.

Comment: It seems that, as of today, there's no solution for this in Ubuntu 16.10. There's a bug in Pipelight where the script can't download the Unity3D plugin. To check this, install first [pipelight-multi] (https://launchpad.net/~pipelight/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+build/9708266/+files/pipelight-multi_0.2.8.2~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb) and [pipelight] (https://launchpad.net/~pipelight/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+build/9708266/+files/pipelight_0.2.8.2~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb), then enter in console  `# pipelight-plugin --enable unity3d`. It will try to download the plugin three times without success.

Answer (score 1):

I did the source route and did it like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine-staging
sudo apt-get build-dep wine-staging
wget https://bitbucket.org/mmueller2012/pipelight/get/v0.2.8.1.tar.gz
tar -xzf v0.2.8.1.tar.gz
cd mmueller2012-pipelight-8a1bdc6c254f
./configure --wine-path=/opt/wine-staging/bin/wine
make
sudo make install
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable flash
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable widevine
sudo pipelight-plugin --update
sudo pipelight-plugin --create-mozilla-plugins
```

For some reason the people that did the ppa have the patched version of wine (called wine-staging), but they don't have pipelight in there. This is nice because it means you don't have to build wine which is huge and you can just build pipelight.

Comment: I got the following error: 
`ERROR: No mingw32-g++ compiler found. Please use --win32-cxx to specify one.`
for this command: `./configure --wine-path=/opt/wine-staging/bin/wine`

Comment: I have Ubuntu 16.04. I had to install `sudo apt-get install mingw-w64`

and `sudo apt-get install libx11-dev` 

But, sudo make intsall says:  `make: *** No rule to make target 'intsall'. Stop.`

Comment: Whoops. That was a typo. It should be "sudo make install". I'll edit the post. Thanks.

Comment: For your first comment which I think you got past, this probably would have helped: sudo apt build-dep wine

Comment: @Sadee `mingw32-g++` is a dependency. Try `sudo apt install mingw32-g++`. From their site:  You also need to check that the following dependencies are fulfilled (you can skip mingw if you want to use wineg++ or the precompiled binaries):

libc6-dev, libx11-dev, mingw-w64, g++-mingw-w64, make, g++, sed

Answer (score 0):

It's because pipelight hasn't been specifically compiled for 16.04.  Apt-get looks for the version that is compiled for your version of the OS.  Just install the 15.10 version.  Works fine.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

You can change manually in system configuration - software and updates searh for the PPA and change xenial to wily. I did that and worked well.