# Unable to locate pipelight-multi package

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, update-manager, pipelight

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight-multi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done 

E: Unable to locate package pipelight-multi
```

I got that error, how do I fix this?

Comment: Did you add the 3rd party repository containing pipelight?  Did you update your package lists afterward (apt-get update)?

Comment: @ubfan1 The Pipelight PPA has not released a `pipelight-multi` package for Ubuntu 16.04 yet. @JWhatDoe What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: @NickWeinberg I am running 16.04

Answer (score 1):

Pipelight has not yet been packaged for Ubuntu 16.04. There are several options for getting it to work; I will not list them here, because they have been explained at [Can't install pipelight ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760898/cant-install-pipelight-ubuntu-16-04) .

If your intent is to get Netflix working, the simplest option is just to install Google Chrome. Netflix is known to work out-of-the-box, with no additional setup, on Google Chrome on Ubuntu 16.04 (but not on Chromium). You can download Google Chrome for Linux at http://google.com/chrome

Comment: It doesn't work HBONow

Comment: Have you tried installing Google Chrome, and then loading HBO Now in Chrome? If not, please go to http://google.com/chrome and follow the instructions.

Comment: You could also try adding `ppa:flexiondotorg/hal-flash` in your Software Sources settings, then opening a terminal and running `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt install hal-flash`

Comment: I installed it `sudo apt-get install libhal1-flash` and its still looping...

Comment: check my comment

Comment: What do you mean by "it's still looping?" I'm not sure what you're referring to.

Comment: http://imgur.com/xFwIVSv , I uploaded the image, circle loading looping thingy, it just keeps going on and on.

Comment: If you use an ad blocker, make sure it's disabled and refresh the page. Other than that, unfortunately I'm not sure what else to try. Sorry :(