# Ubuntu Error in terminal and software

Tags: apt, software-sources, ubuntu-store

I can't find most of the applications in the Ubuntu software store. If I go to the terminal and try to install Fortran, for example, using `sudo apt-get install gfortran`, this is what I get:

```
E: El paquete «gfortran» no tiene un candidato para la instalación
```

Translated:

```
E: Package 'gfortran' has no installation candidate
```

I'm new in Linux and so far I haven't found a solution to this specific problem. If any one could help me I would be soooo grateful! Thanks for your time

Comment: Related: [What does Package <package> has no installation candidate mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14685/what-does-package-package-has-no-installation-candidate-mean)

Comment: Are you sure that's the full error message? Looking up similar errors, I can't find any that are just one line. Normally they say something like "*Package gfortran is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source*"

Answer (score 1):

`gfortran` is located in the universe repository - please ensure that you have 'Community-maintained free and open-source software' selected in the "Software & Updates" program, as shown below.[image]

After adding this repository, you will need to let "Software & Updates" refresh the list of available packages.

---

From the terminal, enter the commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gfortran
```