# E: Package 'libpng12-dev' has no installation candidate

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I use Ubuntu 18.04 bionic and I get this error message when I try to install `libpng12-dev` package.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. Please take a moment to review [What topics can I ask about here?](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), Your question is about a pre-release version and is expected to have issues. Some pre-release questions are considered on-topic see [When are questions about “ubuntu+1” appropriate?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/871/when-are-questions-about-ubuntu1-appropriate). [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: This question is not specific to the beta version as such - there is still no such package in 18.04.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does “Package <package> has no installation candidate” mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14685/what-does-package-package-has-no-installation-candidate-mean)

Comment: Voting to reopen - 18.04 is no longer pre-release, the question is still valid, and a trickle of users continue to encounter this.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The package `libpng12-dev` was dropped after 16.04. It's been gone a long time.

Try `libpng-dev`.

Comment: Thank you!
I am not an Ubuntu expert and found it here: https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

If the above solution did not work try doing then reinstall the libpng-dev:

```
apt upgrade && apt-get install apt-utils
```