# install php7.01-xml using Synaptic package manager

Tags: 14.04, php, synaptic

for our **website** , I tried to install simplexml on **ubuntu 14.04 , php - 7.1**  using below command :

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml
```

I got error as below image :

[image]

than i found [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35593521/php-7-simplexml) , in that they mentioned installing the package **php7.01-xml** using the [Synaptic package manager](https://packages.debian.org/sid/php7.1-xml) , please guide me how i can install using Synaptic package manager ?

Comment: Try to install `libxslt1.1`, this should give more information about why it can't be installed.

Comment: P.S. : the result will be the same if you try to install with Synaptic; it does the same thing.

Comment: @fkraiem when i tried to install  `libxslt1.1` , i got this `E: Package 'libxslt1.1' has no installation candidate
`

Comment: Then your sources are messed up; `libxslt1.1` is available [in all currently supported Ubuntu versions](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libxslt1.1&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all), including 14.04.

Comment: @fkraiem i followed [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14685/what-does-package-package-has-no-installation-candidate-mean) & tried `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/libxslt1-dbg` , then i got error : `Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:chris-lea/libxslt1-dbg'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.`

Comment: @fkraiem using this [link](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/amd64/libxslt1-dbg) , i tried this : `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu/precise/amd64/libxslt1-dbg` it telling `Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.`

Comment: You clearly have no idea what you are doing; no wonder your sources are messed up...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71338/discussion-between-spylh9999ggr-and-fkraiem).

Comment: No, I'm not interested in fixing your sources.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/q/124017/)