# Cannot install net-tools in Ubuntu 20.04 focal

Tags: networking, package-management, 20.04

Iḿ trying to run the command

```
ifconfig
```

The output is:

```
Command 'ifconfig' not found, did you mean:
 
command 'iconfig' from deb ipmiutil (3.1.5-1)   
command 'pifconfig' from deb python3-ethtool (0.14-3build1)   
command 'fconfig' from deb redboot-tools (0.7build3)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

I tried to install it via:

```
sudo apt-get install net-tools
```

But didn't work:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
 Package net-tools is not available, but is referred to by another
 package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
 obsoleted, or is only available from another source
E: Package 'net-tools' has no installation candidate
```

I'm running Ubuntu 20-04, and searched on ubuntu.packages.com and found this result:

[image: package is there]

What am I doing wrong?

#### Update

I was able to solve the problem following this topic:

[What does "Package <package> has no installation candidate" mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14685/what-does-package-package-has-no-installation-candidate-mean)

Thank you all for the replies.

Comment: Why do you have 14.04 tagged here?  Also, have you ran `sudo apt update` before trying to install the `net-tools` package?

Comment: Have you run `apt update` recently?  It sounds like you installed but didn't update your repository data, and this is a Common Occurrence unfortunately.

Comment: @Terrance, I didn't find 20.04 on tags. Sorry. I tried that command but  nothing happens, keeps showing the same error.

Comment: @N0rbert - no, it doesn't. Everything is pretty much the same as shown on that link.

Comment: @Thomas Ward I tried that, but it doesn't  solve. I don't know what to do. Thanks everyone for the tips but I'm stuck with this.

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1257084/edit) your question and add the output of `sudo apt update`?  Sounds like your repositories are not correct or something is wrong with them.  I have 20.04 in a VM and it does show `net-tools` for install and it is installed.

Comment: @Terrance, thanks for your help. I don't remember the result of that command, but I was able to solve the problem following steps on other post. I'll update my post. Thanks.