# E: Package 'python-scipy' has no installation candidate Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, python

I've been trying to install some Python libraries and packages and keep getting this error. This is a sample but the same issue i face with matplotlib and panda and so on.

```
sudo apt-get install python-scipy 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-scipy is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python-scipy' has no installation candidate
```

I tried enabling universe repository andit turns out it is already enabled. So i can't figure out the issue yet.
Thank in advance for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Package <package> has no installation candidate" mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14685/what-does-package-package-has-no-installation-candidate-mean)

Comment: The package is python2 specific, python2 is EOL & all non-ported code was largely removed from repositories (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-scipy/+publishinghistory); both Debian & Ubuntu.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The package you want is [`python3-scipy`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python3-scipy), not `python-scipy`. It can be installed using:

```
apt install python3-scipy
```

You might be better off to install `scipy` via [`pip`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/) (for Python 2) or `pip3` (for Python 3). `pip` is a package manager for Python packages.

```
pip install scipy
```

or

```
pip3 install scipy
```

If you run into a similar problem in the future, you can use `pip3 search scipy` with the relevant search term to look for the required package. Check out `man pip3` for the details.

Answer (score 2):

Python 2 is EOL, but...

you can still install this package by downloading it from 18.04 LTS [repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python-scipy) with

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-scipy/python-scipy_0.19.1-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./python-scipy_0.19.1-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

and then use it was planned.

---

Note: what is interesting - the 20.04 LTS repository has NumPy, but does not have SciPy. Very strange decision as from user point-of-view.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this in Ubuntu

sudo apt install python3-numpy python3-scipy python3-matplotlib python3-pandas python3-sympy python3-nose