# E: Package 'python-scipy' has no installation candidate

Tags: apt, package-management, python, pip

Upon installing a software, I am finding the following error multiple times:

```
$ sudo python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 24, in <module>
    from software_name import PACKAGE_NAME
  File "/home/username/Softwares/software_name/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
import scipy
ImportError: No module named scipy
```

I can install many of the missing modules with, e.g., `sudo apt-get install -y python-numpy`, but sometimes I get:

```
username@username:~/Softwares/software_name$ sudo apt-get install -y python-scipy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-scipy is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python-scipy' has no installation candidate
```

And I am really not sure what is going on? I have read on [another thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/1277010/543795) that the 20.04 LTS repository has NumPy, but does not have SciPy.

EDIT:

```
$ sudo apt install python-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-pip is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  python3-pip

E: Package 'python-pip' has no installation candidate

$ pip install scipy
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (1.3.3)

$ sudo apt install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (20.0.2-5ubuntu1.6).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ sudo pip install scipy
[sudo] password for user_name: 
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (1.3.3)

$ python --version
Python 2.7.18
```

Comment: `However the following packages replace it:
  python3-pip`, updated my answer :-)

Comment: `scipy` is already installed for `python3`.

Comment: @pLumo see the new edits

Comment: What are the name and download URL of "a software"?

Comment: @Py-ser, see my update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best source for looking up packages in ubuntu repositories is [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/)

You can [search for scipy](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-scipy) and will see, that it was taken out from the `universe` after 18.04.

I can only speculate about the reason, maybe no maintainer for the package could be found.

However, you can easily install it via `pip`:

```bsh
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip install scipy
```

---

Note, that `pip` will default to install a package to your local user. If you need to run a `python` script with `sudo` or another user, you need to install it systemwide with:

```bsh
sudo pip install scipy
```

---

If your `python` still not recognize the package, you may need to check if `python` maybe links to `python2`. Check with `python --version`.

Comment: Not really, please see the edit

Comment: edited again, no luck. What if, indeed, python links to python2?

Comment: you run `python3 myscript`. Or install `sudo apt install python-is-python3` package