# rst2man: configure: error: rst2man is required

Tags: apt, python

I am trying to install the latest version of BlueZ from remote (https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git) using the following steps:-

```
./bootstrap
./configure --disable-dependency-tracking
make
```

However, the configure process fails with the following:-

```
checking systemd user unit dir... /usr/lib/systemd/user

checking for rst2man... no
checking for rst2man.py... no
configure: error: rst2man is required
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.
```

After a quick search online, I found that in order to satisfy this requirement, I have to install python-docutils, but this is always failing for me with the following

```
$ sudo apt -y install python-docutils

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package python-docutils is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python-docutils' has no installation candidate
```

I followed the instructions in [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1383002/e-package-python-scipy-has-no-installation-candidate) but still no luck, I always get the above error message. Any idea how I can install python-docutils or rst2man?

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Linux 5.15.0-48-generic).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me

```
sudo apt -y install python3-docutils
```

seemed to work on Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye).

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Don't put a -y in an apt command on SO. We need to know what we are going to install.