# Unable to locate package python-xcbgen

Tags: apt, 20.04, python

I'm trying to install polybar and python-xcbgen is a dependency. For some reason  apt cannot find it. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and as far as I know all of the official Ubuntu repositories are listed in /etc/apt/sources.list. I don't know wh it cannot find it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Package <package> has no installation candidate" mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14685/what-does-package-package-has-no-installation-candidate-mean)

Comment: @karel I understand what the error means. I couldn't find a repository that had "python-xcbgen". I have come to find out, that since updating to python3 the package I was looking for is now "python3-xcbgen".

Comment: The answer to your question is at the linked duplicate question here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1276856/ python-xcbgen package has been discontinued in 20.04 because Python 2.x is no longer being maintained.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
apt install python3-xcbgen
```