# Package 'octave-octcdf' has no installation candidate (Ubuntu 18 LTS)

Tags: package-management, dependencies, octave

I need to install `octave-octcdf` package to work with Octave. I tried, `sudo apt-get install -y octave-octcdf`. But this receives an error as following;

```
user@PowerEdge-R540:~/user/tools$ sudo apt-get install -y octave-octcdf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package octave-octcdf is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'octave-octcdf' has no installation candidate
```

Can anyone help to properly install `octave-octcdf` package?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Package <package> has no installation candidate" mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14685/what-does-package-package-has-no-installation-candidate-mean) The last release that contains octave-octcdf in its default repositories is 16.04, but it's unclear what release you are asking about.

Comment: @Karel My Ubuntu is 18 LTS. I was able to install the package in 16.04 version. But couldn't in 18?

Comment: Because of https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/octave-octcdf and then https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=octave-octcdf .

Comment: Ubuntu has both *yy.mm* releases (the main desktop & server releases, eg Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) and as a different product releases using the *yy* format such as Ubuntu Core 18.  The *yy* releases are not generally referred to as LTS as they all have 10 years of support (which is longer than 18.04 LTS, though 18.04's life can be extended via ESM). You mean a 18.04 system I gather, so please use it, and not 18 which maybe seen as implying Ubuntu Core 18 which is *snap* only, and `apt-get` commands don't apply.  Ubuntu has had *year* only releases since 2016.